# Including javascript libraries into Snowflake UDFs

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm interested in getting JS UDFs to work without pasting a bunch of code at the beginning of the function.

Anyone knows if there is any similar way to include javascript libraries in UDFs as BigQuery does?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-javascript-libraries

I would love to know if it's at least in Snowflake's roadmap or if there is another method to handle this kind of cases.

Comment: Would using External Functions (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions.html) meet your use case?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nick. We have tried that already. But unfortunately external functions introduce some latency that we are trying to avoid.

Comment: You could consider Java UDFs. You can write the Java in Eclipse, JBuilder, etc., and use a compiled JAR file in Snowflake. This approach allows you to use multiple class libraries, and share code across UDFs. A single class can drive multiple Java UDFs.

Answer (score 1):

[Restrictions on Stored Procedures](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#restrictions-on-stored-procedures):

> Stored procedures have the following restrictions:
>
> - The JavaScript code cannot call the JavaScript eval() function.
> - JavaScript stored procedures support access to the standard JavaScript library. Note that this excludes many objects and methods typically provided by browsers. **There is no mechanism to import, include, or call additional libraries. Allowing 3rd-party libraries could create security holes.**